# Is it possible to use a category to "bootstrap" a bunch of related categories?

Tags: groovy, categories

I have a category class that I want to "Use" that acts on a third-party service class. The service class has a bunch of xxxRequest and xxxResponse classes plus additional child classes for data for each xxx call.

I want to automatically apply categories to each of the additional classes at the same time as the service category is applied, with the same scope.

I could list all the category classes in the use block but there are a lot and I don't want to expose that detail. The base classes are out of my control so I can't use @category/@mixin.

Currently I have a static initialise method in my service category that does a series of mixin calls (as well as adding the odd extra constructor). This works ok but doesn't provide the scoping I want.

Is there an easier way that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to `use` many categories at once in the same block of code but you don't want to list all those categories each time you want to use them (please correct me if that is not what you meant), you can put that long `use` inside a method that takes a block of code (a Closure) as a parameter and then use that method instead of the long `use`. Something like:

```
@Category(String)
class ShoutCategory {
    def shout() {
        this.toUpperCase() + '!'
    }
}

@Category(Integer)
class ToEnglishCategory {
    def toEnglish() {
        // Only works for integers in 0..5 for now...
        ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'][this]
    }
}

def useAwesomeExtensions(Closure cl) {
    use (ShoutCategory, ToEnglishCategory) {
        cl()
    }
}

useAwesomeExtensions {
    // Here we can do all sorts of magic things.
    println 3.toEnglish().shout() // Outputs "THREE!"
}

// "hello".shout() -> Would throw a MissingMethodException here
```

In this silly example, the String and Integer classes would be the classes that you want to augment but you don't have access to, and the `useAwesomeExtensions` acts like a big category that includes a bunch of other categories. Hope that helps :)

Comment: That is sort of what I want, except to say use(AwesomeExtensions) and have the AwesomeExtensions category set up ShoutCategory and ToEnglishCategory rather than using a separate closure

Comment: @MichaelRutherfurd Yeah, I tried using `@Mixin` to mix the categories into a bigger category, but it didn't seem to work. Though the usage is slightly different, does this solution adapt to what you want to achieve?